# How to restore cherry mobile quartz messing up the build prop

Tags: rooting

I just bought my Cherry Mobile Quartz last week, and it is rooted. I edited the build prop name and changed it to Cherry Mobile Flare. After that, I rebooted my phone, and now it's stuck on the android logo.

I tried to repair it in service center, but the stock rom is not available yet. I don't have any backup of the build prop, and the stock recovery didn't work.

How can I fix my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your phone to recovery.

Use adb to pull (read as copy) the build.prop from ROM/device

> adb pull /system/build.prop c:\

Edit it back the way that it was.

*Once edited save as normal*

Use adb to push (read as paste) the build.prop to ROM/device

> adb shell chmod 0644 /system/build.prop
>
> adb remount

.....then

> adb push c:\build.prop /system/

Reboot

> adb reboot

Or

> adb shell reboot